# Bean Injection not happening in controller when run via spring boot Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-test

I have created a spring boot web application with Rest based apis.
My controller has a service which is autowired and injected when the application is started normally when run via main application. However if i run my integration test for that controller. I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'com.xyz.test.service.LolService' available: expected
 at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is my controller class.

```
package com.xyz.test.controller;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.xyz.test.model.Lol;
import com.xyz.test.service.LolProcessingService;
import com.xyz.test.service.LolService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Slf4j
public class CalorieController {

    @Autowired
    private LoleService lolService;

    @Autowired
    private LolProcessingService lolProcessingService;


    @PostMapping("/lol")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public FoodIntake createLol( @Valid @RequestBody Lol lol) throws Exception {
        return lolProcessingService.processNewLol(lol);
    }
}
```

This is my service class

```
package com.xyz.test.service.impl;
   @Service
    public class LolServiceImpl implements LolService{

        @Autowired
        private LolRepository lolRepository;

    //some methods
    }
```

And this is my Integration test class.

```
package com.xyz.test.rest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.xyz.test.controller.CalorieController;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = CalorieController.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class LolControllerTest {


    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();


    @Test
    public void testabc() throws JSONException {
        headers.add("Authorization","Basic cGFtcGxlOnBhbXBsZTEyMw==");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                createURLWithPort("/api/lol/pample"),
                HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        String expected = "[]";

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, response.getBody(), false);
    }

    private String createURLWithPort(String uri) {
        return "http://localhost:" + port + uri;
    }


}
```

And finally this is main application

```
package com.xyz.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class SpringbootSecurityMysqlApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootSecurityMysqlApplication.class, args);
    }

    //bean for making http external calls
    @Bean 
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

I dont understand why the test class doesnt start properly with proper injection of beans.. I need help in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the service class to the test annotation?

Comment: @daniu din't get your suggestion.. u mean autowiring that service in my test class?? If so i tried that as well. same issue even then

Comment: replace CalorieController.class with your SpringbootSecurityMysqlApplication .class.

Comment: I meant `@SpringBootTest(LolServiceImpl.class, CalorieController.class) `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't specify `classes` parameter for the @SpringBootTest annotation.

Using it in following way

```
 @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

will cause Spring Boot to look for configuration class in current package, then parent package etc.. eventually finding your `SpringbootSecurityMysqlApplication`. This will test full application including all layers.

In case you want to test the controller in isolation with mocked service use

```
@WebMvcTest(CalorieController.class)
```

and provide mock bean for the service in your test

```
@MockBean
private LoleService lolService;
```